# npm start / reactjs - how to keep the browser from reloading on save

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I am working with applications bootstrapped with create-react-app and everything works very well. I have been up and down the docs provided here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts

but can't find an answer to my question. Simply: when using `npm start` to run an application in development how do I tell npm *not* to reload the browser with every save? Reloads can be painful when you've got Chrome's React and Redux devtools extensions right where you want them.

I'm sure the answer is in the layout of these scripts from package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

but for the life of me I can't find any details on the greasy grimy gopher guts of how these scripts work. Is this a node.js question? Pointers to any top-level documentation are appreciated. I'm not sure where to start...

Edit: I should add that I learned ReactJS prior to using creat-react-app and in the online stackskills class I took we installed react* manually and in this environment the browser did not reload automatically and all errors/warnings/etc were shown only in the terminal running `npm start`, not in the browser. This is my preferred setup...

@Sag1v: the webpack info provided by npm is:

```
$ npm list | grep webpack
| +-- case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin@1.1.4
| +-- extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1
| | `-- webpack-sources@0.1.4
| +-- html-webpack-plugin@2.24.0
| +-- webpack@1.14.0
| | `-- webpack-core@0.6.9
| +-- webpack-dev-server@1.16.2
| | `-- webpack-dev-middleware@1.10.0
| +-- webpack-manifest-plugin@1.1.0
```

Comment: I think if you want to change settings to the way  create-react-app works for you, then you would need to eject. This can be done with npm run eject. If you do this tho you are on your own.

Comment: Can you post you webpack configurations? I think you are running the dev server with HMRE

Comment: @Sag1v: I don't know? There seem to be no webpack guts in my project directory. I have posted the webpack info in an edit to my original post.

Comment: @promisified: thanks, that looks like where I may have to go. Not going to try it in this production application though...